# PHP $_POST variable not set after using jQuery to disable pressed button and change its text

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

I have PHP code with several buttons in one form (for simplicity only two buttons in this case). After the button is pressed, the server may take few seconds to process time-complex stuff (i.e. external API calls - not included in the example bellow). I am looking for the simplest solution to achieve the following after the button is pressed:

- prevent multiple form submission with making pressed button disabled and its text changed to 'Please wait...',
- after the form is submitted (**important:** the same PHP page must be loaded) the $_POST variable should be set and become readable in PHP to determine which of the buttons have been clicked.

I have the following code, which disable pressed button and change its text successfully but the PHP **$_POST variable is not set** somehow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    // Disable the clicked button and change its text
    var buttonText = $(this).text();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).text('Please wait...');

    // Submit the form
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- PHP Code -->
<?php
$zac = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $buttonValue = $_POST['button'];

        if ($buttonValue === 'one') {
            $zac = 'first button has been clicked';
        } elseif ($buttonValue === 'two') {
            $zac = 'second button has been clicked';
        }
    }
}
?>

<!-- Form -->
<h1>Button Pressed: <?php echo $zac; ?></h1>
<form method="post" action="">
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="one" id="button1">Button 1</button>
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="two" id="button2">Button 2</button>
</form>

<!-- CDN jQuery 3.6.0 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you submit a form via JS, button values aren't sent, because the button wasn't used to trigger the submission directly. This is documented already: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Your whole JS routine seems a bit pointless though...the form will start submitting immediately

Comment: I think you should start with changing buttons' name properties. Same name on both buttons but different value will cause some trouble, probably the 2nd button will override the 1st button's value submitted. Second thing, when you click one of the buttons it will actually submit the form but you submit the form second time using `submit()` method.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN no. If the buttons were actually used to submit, only the value of the button that was pressed would be sent. But as I've already pointed out that isn't what is happening here.  Although you're right that it may submit automatically as well, without the JS. Depending how fast the JS runs though, that might get there first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {

        const form = $(this).closest('form');

        if (form.data("submitted")) {  // if already submitted
            console.log("Submit aborted (" + Math.random() + ")")   // for debugging
            return false;
        }

        console.log("Submit! (" + Math.random() + ")");  // for debugging

        form.data("submitted", true);   // store the flag into the form element
        $(this).text("Please wait...");

        // form.submit(); -- not needed
    });
});
```

The basic problem is that when you disable the button,  its value cannot be sent with a *'submit'*.

Instead of disabling the button, you can set a flag and test it: if the form has already been submitted you can ignore the button click

Comment: @ Pippo: your example works, but the click button doesn't get disabled on click. If I add $(this).prop('disabled', true); than $_POST variable is not set. Do you happen to have solution for that too?

Comment: As you also understood, by disabling the button, its value cannot be sent with a *'submit'*.
There are many possible solutions, but they are more complex.
With the method I suggested you get the same result even if no button is disabled (you always have the indication *'Please wait...'*

Comment: @ Pippo: I have tested your solution precisely and noticed that multiple form submission is not prevented on time-consuming server tasks as button does not get disabled.

Comment: @TaKo you are right: I had previously tried with Firefox which has a slightly different behavior and it worked, but with Chrome it doesn't work.
I edited the answer and added an explicit `return false;` when the *submit* shouldn't be done. I also removed `form.submit();` which becomes redundant at this point. 
Now it works as expected.
Tested with Firefox, Chrome and Edge